# arabic string truncate by word

Tags: php, arabic

Want to truncate arabic string by word

**I tried**

```
function mb_str_word_count($string, $format = 0, $charlist = '[]') {
    mb_internal_encoding( 'UTF-8');
    mb_regex_encoding( 'UTF-8');

    $words = mb_split('[^\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]', $string);
    switch ($format) {
        case 0:
            return count($words);
            break;
        case 1:
        case 2:
            return $words;
            break;
        default:
            return $words;
            break;
    }
};
function limit_text($text, $limit) {
    //echo str_word_count($text, 0);//exit;
    if (mb_str_word_count($text, 0) > $limit) {
        $words = mb_str_word_count($text, 2);
        $pos = array_keys($words);
        $text = substr($text, 0, $pos[$limit]);
    }
    return $text;
}
$text='
الوقائع
ــــ أسندت النيابة العامة إلى المتهم مسلم محمد البراك أنه في تاريخ 15/10/2012 بدائرة مباحث أمن الدولة:
"طعن علنا وفي مكان عام عن طريق القول في حقوق الأمير وسلطته وعاب في ذاته وتطاول على مسند الإمارة بأن وجه له خلال ندوة عامة العبارات والألفاظ المبينة بالأوراق وذلك على النحو المبين بالتحقيقات".
ــــ وخلصت النيابة العامة إلى أن المتهم "قد ارتكب الجناية المؤثمة بالمادة (25) من القانون رقم (31) لسنة 1970 بتعديل بعض أحكام قانون الجزاء"، وطلبت النيابة العامة من محكمة الجنايات معاقبة المتهم طبقا لمادة الاتهام، وأرفقت بتقرير الاتهام ما وصفته بقائمة "بأدلة الثبوت".
ــــ وفي تحقيقات النيابة العامة، أنكر المتهم جميع الاتهامات المسندة إليه، كما أنكرها أمام المحكمة الموقرة، وقد أوضح أمام النيابة العامة إن ما قاله إنما كان نصحا ولم يكن قصده الإساءة إلى الأمير.
ــــ كما طلب المتهم أمام النيابة العامة سماع شهادة كل من: رئيس مجلس الوزراء الشيخ جابر المبارك الحمد الصباح، والسيد أنس الصالح وزير التجارة والصناعة، والسيد خالد سلطان بن عيسى نائب رئيس مجلس الأمة السابق، والسيد وليد الجري، والسيد جمعان الحربش، والسيد أحمد الديين.
ــــ وبتاريخ 15/4/2013، أصدرت محكمة أول درجة حكمها المطعون عليه، والذي قضت فيه بحبس المتهم خمس سنوات مع الشغل والنفاذ.
ــــ وفور صدور الحكم، طعن المتهم عليه بطريق الاستئناف. وفي أول جلسة أمام محكمة الاستئناف بتاريخ 29/4/2013، قررت المحكمة وقف تنفيذ الحكم المطعون عليه لحين الفصل في الاستئناف، وقررت تأجيل نظر الدعوى لجلسة 13/5/2013 بناء على طلب الدفاع للاطلاع والاستعداد.';
echo limit_text($text,100);
```

but its not working,
so please help me

**need logic which supports to english text too**

Comment: Don't forget to save your file as UTF-8 without BOM. also your Page has needs the UTF-8 Metatag in your html header.

Comment: <meta charset="utf-8" /> is present but 'Don't forget to save your file as UTF-8 without BOM' means?

Comment: You can save your file in different Encoding, ANSI, UTF-8 and UTF-8 without BOM. UTF-8 without BOM is the standard used Encoding in PHP. Since you hardcoded arabic characters in a file the string will be read depending on the system language setup. So your Webserver which is probably not arabic won't be able to read it when it's not UTF-8 without BOM. Notepad++ has the possibility to change the encoding. Windows' Editor Notepad has also, it's called Unicode there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working with simple

```
$words = mb_split('\s', $string);
```

whole function:

```
function mb_str_word_count($string, $format = 0, $charlist = '[]') {
    $string=  trim($string);
    $words = mb_split('\s', $string);
    switch ($format) {
        case 0:
            return count($words);
            break;
        case 1:
        case 2:
            return $words;
            break;
        default:
            return $words;
            break;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need all of this code to truncate string you can use something like this

```
mb_substr($text,0,100,"UTF-8");
```

in your code this line will return noting

```
$words = mb_split('[^\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]', $string);
```

you can change the Regexp to the following line but it will return the whole Arabic string not character array

```
mb_split("/([\x{0621}-\x{064A}])/u", $string)
```

Comment: but then how to combine to display?

Comment: you can use echo mb_substr($text,0,100,"UTF-8"); to display part of the text I don't really understand your question in the comment

Comment: its not working for english text,look i tried with string "Test Article Description" and getting none,her $word array:array(25) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" [4]=> string(0) "" [5]=> string(0) "" [6]=> string(0) "" [7]=> string(0) "" [8]=> string(0) "" [9]=> string(0) "" [10]=> string(0) "" [11]=> string(0) "" [12]=> string(0) "" [13]=> string(0) "" [14]=> string(0) "" [15]=> string(0) "" [16]=> string(0) "" [17]=> string(0) "" [18]=> string(0) "" [19]=> string(0) "" [20]=> string(0) "" [21]=> string(0) "" [22]=> ...